# BigQuery Stored Procedure - Use variable in UPDATE statement for table name

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use a while loop in a stored procedure to update a list of tables. When trying to execute the below code, I am getting the error: `Table name "table_name" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request`. It seems the stored procedure is not correctly reading the variable `table_name` when it is after `UPDATE`. Is this intentionally not supported?

```sql
DECLARE table_names ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE table_name STRING;
DECLARE INDEX INT64 DEFAULT 0;

SET table_names = [
  "`dev.table`",
  "`dev.table2`"
];

BEGIN
  WHILE INDEX < 2 DO
    SET table_name = table_names[OFFSET(INDEX)];
    SELECT table_name;
    UPDATE table_name
    SET name = "new_name"
    WHERE name = "old_name";
    SET INDEX = INDEX + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in below fragment of script

```
UPDATE table_name
SET name = "new_name"
WHERE name = "old_name";
```

you should use [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) - something like below

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
UPDATE ''' || table_name || '''
SET name = "new_name"
WHERE name = "old_name"''';
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. How exactly does the concatenation work in `'''UPDATE || table_name || '''`? Why is that required?

Comment: concatenation is needed to assemble statement that will be run by `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` - please consider also voting up the answer